# Restore scene data and state after multiple operations

Tags: python, add-on, scene

I am working on an addon that will perform various operations in a scene (transformations, assigning materials, setting physics, adding particles, so on) at the press of a key.
What I want is to be able to reset everything to the exact state it had before pressing the key. I need to know what option do I have in order to achieve this.

So far, I have considered the following approaches:

- using undo (the problem is that the undo has a limit of steps and my operations might exceed them, so reverting might leave me in the middle of what has changed)
- saving the scene just before the key is pressed then reload it when I want to restore everything (I don't know if this will also reset the layout or the rendering mode, which I don't want - I only want the scene to go back to what it was, the UI should not change)
- saving all the steps in an array then process them backwards (say, if I applied a transform, save it with the initial value, then, when restoring the scene, apply the transform once more with that saved value). this is the most complicated, I guess
- another option that I tested was copying the scene then removing it and going back to the initial scene. I did a linked, orphaned copy but it looks like operations are reflected in the initial scene, too. I tried with a full copy, but the operations are done over the objects of the initial scene.

I wonder if there's something that allows you to save a snapshot of everything inside the scene (transforms, properties, materials, timeline) then go back to it at a later point.

Comment: Surely saving the Blend file and then reloading it later would do that?

Comment: I am exploring the option of making a copy of the scene, doing operations there, then deleting it. Saving and reloading scene would be a last resort if this one doesn't work now (I added the option in my question to explain why it doesn't so far)

Comment: Fair enough. Saving and reloading the Blend file also saves the UI layout of course although you can uncheck the option to reload it with the Blend file, either for single files on the N panel in the File browser or in Preferences > Save & Load > Blend files > Load UI which makes it permanent.

Comment: OK, so you listed pretty much all viable ways to do that, but why did they not work for you? What's wrong with copying the scene for example? If you copy it without linking any data, it will remain as it is while you work on another copy.

Comment: " I did a [...] orphaned copy but it looks like operations are reflected in the initial scene, too" - how exactly did you do that? In this case it is easiest to just use the operator bpy.ops.scene.new(type='FULL_COPY') and then it becomes the active scene so you can access it as active. If you do it with bpy.context.scene.copy() this will make a copy with all data in it linked and you would have to make sure you make copies of all data-blocks in the scene, which seems like a lot of complex work that I suspect you did not do and that's why operations are done on linked objects in both copies.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys, I just wanted to know if there was some other way of doing this directly through the API, maybe

Comment: No "automatic" way to do this. It's way too specific for any general functions to exist for this. I think copying the scene should work fine.

Comment: When I make a full copy, the objects are also duplicated but my operations still reference the original ones. I need to be able to match the copies to the originals somehow so I can do the operations in the new scene

Comment: It's not possible to answer this in a single answer, that's just work you have to do. You have to figure out how to program that. It also depends on the circumstances and specifics of your situation that only you currently know.